# Best practice for installing python modules from an arbitrary VCS repository

Tags: python, version-control, module, easy-install

I'm newish to the python ecosystem, and have a question about module editing.

I use a bunch of third-party modules, distributed on PyPi.  Coming from a C and Java background, I love the ease of `easy_install <whatever>`.  This is a new, wonderful world, but the model breaks down when I want to edit the newly installed module for two reasons:

1. The `egg` files may be stored in a folder or archive somewhere crazy on the file system.
2. Using an `egg` seems to preclude using the version control system of the originating project, just as using a debian package precludes development from an originating VCS repository.

What is the best practice for installing modules from an arbitrary VCS repository?  I want to be able to continue to `import foomodule` in other scripts.  And if I modify the module's source code, will I need to perform any additional commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting to do development but have the developed version be handled as an egg by the system (for instance to get entry-points)? If so then you should check out the source and use [Development Mode](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#development-mode) by doing:

```
python setup.py develop
```

If the project happens to not be a setuptools based project, which is required for the above, a quick work-around is this command:

```
python -c "import setuptools; execfile('setup.py')" develop
```

Almost everything you ever wanted to know about setuptools (the basis of easy_install) is available from the the [setuptools docs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools). Also there are [docs for easy_install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall).

Development mode adds the project to your import path in the same way that easy_install does. An changes you make will be available to your apps the next time they import the module.

As others mentioned, you can also directly use version control URLs if you just want to get the latest version as it is now without the ability to edit, but that will only take a snapshot, and indeed creates a normal egg as part of the process. I know for sure it does Subversion and I thought it did others but I can't find the docs on that.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) lets you install files gives a URL to the Subversion, git, Mercurial or bzr repository.

```
pip install -e svn+http://path_to_some_svn/repo#egg=package_name
```

Example:
    pip install -e hg+https://rwilcox@bitbucket.org/ianb/cmdutils#egg=cmdutils

If I wanted to download the latest version of [cmdutils](http://bitbucket.org/ianb/cmdutils). (Random package I decided to pull).

I installed this into a virtualenv (using the -E parameter), and pip installed cmdutls into a src folder at the top level of my virtualenv folder.

```
pip install -E thisIsATest -e hg+https://rwilcox@bitbucket.org/ianb/cmdutils#egg=cmdutils

$  ls thisIsATest/src
cmdutils
```

Comment: Where does this download to sourcecode to?  If I modify the source-code downloaded by `svn`, do I need to run any commands?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info (including an answer to that question)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or symlink your code to somewhere in site-packages.

Comment: What exactly do I add to `PYTHONPATH`?  The folder that contains `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Packages installed by easy_install tend to come from snapshots of the developer's version control, generally made when the developer releases an official version.  You're therefore going to have to choose between convenient automatic downloads via easy_install and up-to-the-minute code updates via version control.  If you pick the latter, you can build and install most packages seen in the python package index directly from a version control checkout by running `python setup.py install`.

If you don't like the default installation directory, you can install to a custom location instead, and export a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable whose value is the path of the installed package's parent folder.

Comment: I am choosing the latter option.  If I am modifying the source code repeatedly, do I need to rerun `python setup.py install` after every modification, or only once?  What does `python setup.py install` do?

Comment: It depends on the package.  If a package was designed to be usable fresh out of version control without a build/install step, then you can just point `PYTHONPATH` at the parent of the checkout directory.  Otherwise, you're going to have to build and possibly install it before it can be safely imported.

`python setup.py install` tells a package made with setuptools or distutils to build itself and install the built files in your system's usual location for add-on python packages.  Here is some documentation: http://docs.python.org/distutils/